# cmd1, cmd2 connect with pipe and save log each commad

Tags: bash, redirect, pipe, stdout, stderr

I'm going to pipe command 1 and command 2.
And the log of that command wants to output to one file.

but log display on terminal...

```
$cmd1 1> result1.out 2> log.txt

$cmd2 result1.out 1> result2.out 2>> log.txt
```

Two commands can be used as a pipe to reduce time.

Each run causes about an hour's difference from the one used by connecting to a pipe.

```
$cmd1 | cmd2 1> result.out 2> log.txt
```

this situation i want to save all log to `log.txt` but log didn't write that file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the pipeline and redirects the stderr of the whole group:

```
{ cmd1 | cmd2 >result.out; } 2>log.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you have:

```
cmd1 | cmd2 >out 2>log
```

That

- pipes the stdout of cmd1 to the stdin of cmd2,
- prints the stderr of cmd1 on the screen,
- saves the stdout of cmd2 to file out,
- and saves the stderr of cmd2 to file log.

You may want:

```
cmd1 2>log1 | cmd2 >out >log2
```

This

- pipes the stdout of cmd1 to the stdin of cmd2,
- saves the stderr of cmd1 to file log1,
- saves the stdout of cmd2 to file out,
- and saves the stderr of cmd2 to file log2.

Comment: thanks...The action starts well but ends in the middle.
Log files and result files are created and actual content is written and terminated in the middle.